# Proving that $\int_C \left(\frac {-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac {x}{x^2+y^2}\right)ds=\varphi(b) - \varphi(a)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, plane-curves

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ be a curve of class $C^1$ and $\varphi:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function such that: $$\forall t\in [a,b], \alpha(t) = ||\alpha(t)||\cdot(\cos(\varphi(t)), \sin(\varphi(t)))$$
> And let $C$ be the path represented by the curve $\alpha$. Prove that: $$\int_C \left(\frac {-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac {x}{x^2+y^2}\right)ds=\varphi(b) - \varphi(a)$$

My first approach was to verify if the field was conservative, but I don't think that's the case. I have no clue on how to solve this. How can this be done?

Comment: First note: what is the curve $\alpha$, geometrically?

Comment: I don't know @JacobA

Comment: Think of the simplest case first, say $\phi(t)=t$... on a different note, how did you check if it was conservative? Can you show that calculation?

Comment: phi is the angle. think like that :) it's as if you go from t to phi to alpha.